# ID attribute not displayed in Browser for Eclipse SWT/RAP HTML components

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rap

We are using RAP with Eclipse SWT to render our application UI in browser.
We want to automate the Testing of Application with selenium, which requires IDs for each HTML component.
But the problem is widgets (Text in this case) does not have "id"  as an attributes visible in the browser.

We have tried using following setData method of Text widget but still id attribute is not visible in browser.

```java
tf_offerId.setData(SWT.SKIN_ID, "myId1");
tf_offerId.setData(SWT.SKIN_CLASS, "myClass");
```

Here is our sample Code.

```java
class A {
  private Text tf_offerId;
  void method1() {
    Composite comp_left = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
    Composite comp = new Composite(comp_left, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl_comp = new GridLayout(3, false);
    gl_comp.marginWidth = 0;
    comp.setLayout(gl_comp);
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false,1, 1));
    Label lbl = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    lbl.setText("Offer Id / Cluster Id");
    lbl.setBackground(new Color(getDisplay(),220,220,220));
    lbl.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    tf_offerId = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);
    tf_offerId.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER,true, false, 1, 1));
    tf_offerId.setToolTipText("Usage:\nsss_pricing/se_configuration-OfferId\nse_calculation-OfferId\nsss_build/sss_validation-ClusterId");
  }
}
```

Please suggest possible solution.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

To identify a widget on the client side it is best to define an dedicated *test attribute* that holds the id used for testing. With this id, the widget can be identified in Selenium.

A discussion of various alternatives to identify widgets on the client side for testing with Selenium can be found here:

[How to write UI tests for RAP with Selenium 2.0](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/04/29/how-to-write-ui-tests-for-rap-with-selenium-2-0/)